# Include comments with post in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, vue.js

Im building a rails app with vue components on several pages. I pass my data to the vue component like so:

`<v-my-component :posts="<%= @post.to_json %>"></v-my-component>`

This works fine and I get my posts as json passed as a prop to my component. However if I want to also include the post comments, how could I do this? I want something like:

```
#posts/show
<v-my-component :posts="<%= @post.wtih(:comment).to_json %>"></v-my-component>
```

my json should look something like:

```
post
    title:"",
    body:"",
    ...,
    comments:[
        {
            id:1,
            comment_body:"",
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the option to [`to_json`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json):

```
<v-my-component :posts="<%= @post.to_json(include: :comments) %>"></v-my-component>
```